# .NET web Async calls to package Azure.Storage.Blobs hang

Tags: .net, vb.net, azure, async-await, azure-blob-storage

**Experience:**
Long time experience with .Net and VB (C#).  Not so long with Azure, Async / Await and Multi threading.

**Summary of issue:**
I wrote a desk top (forms based), proof of concept to upload / list and retrieve videos from Azure Block Store.  This was initially with Sync calls, but I later added to the PoC to make use of the Async calls.  All was well, and I got what I regard as "expected behaviour".  The Async version allowed me to populate a label with "Downloading" and then to clear that label on completion of the download.  In the final solution it will allow the web page to fully load independent of any time needed to down load video material.
The problems arose when I started to move my PoC code into a .NET **web** application.  In this project the identical code hangs at the point the second Async method is called [Await download.Content.CopyToAsync(downloadFileStream)].  By this, I mean it never gets to commented Execution point: C.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Azure.Storage.Blobs
Imports Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Public Class frmBlockStore
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim gWorkingPath As String = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
        Dim sAzFRConnection As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZ_FR_BLOCK_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING")
        If sAzFRConnection <> "" Then
            Dim blobServiceClient As BlobServiceClient = New BlobServiceClient(sAzFRConnection)
            ' Open an existing container
            Dim sFileName As String = "17.5.04.mp4"
            Dim containerClient As BlobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("media")
            If containerClient.Exists Then
                ' Sync calls that work perfectly...
                'Dim blobClient As BlobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(sFileName.ToLower)
                'Dim download As BlobDownloadInfo = blobClient.Download()
                'Dim downloadFileStream As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(gWorkingPath & "DocFiltered_files" & "\" & sFileName)
                'download.Content.CopyTo(downloadFileStream)
                'downloadFileStream.Close()
                Dim lReturn As Task = DownloadVideoAsync(containerClient, sFileName)
                ' Execution point: A
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Async Function DownloadVideoAsync(containerClient As BlobContainerClient, sFileName As String) As Task(Of Long)
        Dim gWorkingPath As String = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
        Dim downloadFileStream As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(gWorkingPath & "DocFiltered_files" & "\" & sFileName)
        Dim blobClient As BlobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(sFileName)
        Dim download As BlobDownloadInfo = Await blobClient.DownloadAsync()
        ' Execution point: B
        Await download.Content.CopyToAsync(downloadFileStream)
        ' Execution point: C
        Dim lLth As Long = downloadFileStream.Length
        downloadFileStream.Close()
        Return lLth
    End Function
End Class
```

On clicking the button the pre-requisite code executes fine and proceeds to the call to DownloadVideoAsync.  I have included the working equivalent sync code, commented out, in the button click event for those that are interested.  Within that function, execution proceeds to 'Await blobClient.DownloadAsync()'.  This function never appears to take very long anyway, as I think it is setting up the download, rather than doing it.  I guess there is some Azure side stuff to do, thus the Async nature of the call.  So upon execution of this statement, the next point of execution is at Execution point: A i.e. back within the calling routine.  This is expected.  Following that it resumes at point Execution point: B.  This is all how the debugger paints it (accepting that the multi threaded nature of what is going on might mean this is actually in parallel?)  The next statement [Await download.Content.CopyToAsync(downloadFileStream)] starts to execute.  We can see in the target file destination folder, that a zero byte file of the specified file name now exists.  However, Execution point: C is never reached and the file at the target destination never achieves any more than a zero byte count.

A virtually identical sync call in a Desktop Application works perfectly as shown below.

```
   Dim lReturn As Task(Of Long) = DownloadVideoAsync(containerClient, "17.5.04.mp4")

   Async Function DownloadVideoAsync(containerClient As BlobContainerClient, sFileName As String) As Task(Of Long)
        Dim gWorkingPath As String = "C:\Work\Source\Web\FindResponse\WebSource\"
        Dim downloadFileStream As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(gWorkingPath & "DocFiltered_files" & "\" & sFileName)

        Dim blobClient As BlobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(sFileName)
        Dim download As BlobDownloadInfo = Await blobClient.DownloadAsync()
        Await download.Content.CopyToAsync(downloadFileStream)

        Dim lLth As Long = downloadFileStream.Length
        downloadFileStream.Close()
        Return lLth
    End Function
```

I should perhaps add that the setting up of a web project that actually managed to compile without errors and warnings was "challenging" and time consuming.  I would recommend anyone attempting to use the Azure tools to embrace the latest version of .NET, load a dev version of the .NET Cord SDK and to use NuGet, rather than "dotnet add", to install the required packages. If your application is old, take backups of your source code at each stage so you can roll back and reconsider your options!

**Environment details:**
Both applications (Desktop and Web) are running in a Visual Studio development environment and are connecting to Azure using a connection string.

Windows 10 home, Version 1903, OS build 18362.719

Visual studio:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.9.13
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.13+28307.718
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03752

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA335
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.14.20131.1
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit   1.0
ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit Visual Studio integration package

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.9.04012.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017

ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.61435.0
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.9.03024.0
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   15.9.03024.0
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

C# Tools   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0
JavaScript UWP Project System

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 - v2.9.20417.1

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   1.0
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

MLGen Package Extension   1.0
MLGen Package Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

MySQL for Visual Studio   1.2.8
Data design and management tools for MySQL. Copyright (c) 2007, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

NuGet Package Manager   4.6.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 ENU   15.0.28224.00
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 ENU

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
ResourcePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
ResourcePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61906.03120
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript Tools   15.9.30524.2002
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools 10.2 for F# 4.5   15.8.0.0.  Commit Hash: 6e26c5bacc8c4201e962f5bdde0a177f82f88691.
Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.2 for F# 4.5

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers

Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.28307.718
The Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a single universal app experience that can reach every device running Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft Windows 10 Software Development Kit.

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

NuGet:

PM> get-package

Id                                  Versions                                 ProjectName
--                                  --------                                 -----------
Azure.Core                          {1.1.0}                                  BlobStore
Azure.Storage.Blobs                 {12.4.0}                                 BlobStore
Azure.Storage.Common                {12.3.0}                                 BlobStore
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces       {1.0.0}                                  BlobStore
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotN... {2.0.1}                                  BlobStore
System.Buffers                      {4.5.0}                                  BlobStore
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource {4.6.0}                                  BlobStore
System.Memory                       {4.5.3}                                  BlobStore
System.Numerics.Vectors             {4.5.0}                                  BlobStore
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.... {4.5.2}                                  BlobStore
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions   {4.5.2}                                  BlobStore

.NET Core SDK 3.1 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're creating a new ASP.NET Web Forms project. If you're starting a new project, I recommend using ASP.NET Core instead.

That said, to [use asynchronous code on ASP.NET Web Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45), you need to:

1. Set `Page.Async` to `true`.
2. Either pass the `Task` (`lReturn` in your example) to `RegisterAsyncTask` (after you wrap it with `PageAsyncTask`), or `await` it and make your event handler `Async Sub`.